# OutputCache - cache only if no params in GET

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

What parameters to use in OutputCache if you want to Cache in case of no params on a page, in other cases not caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [HttpCachePolicy.SetNoServerCaching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setnoservercaching.aspx) in the [HttpApplication.PostMapRequestHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postmaprequesthandler.aspx) event.

See [Making ASP.NET Output Cache Work with Post-Back](http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/making-asp-net-output-cache-work-with-post-back.aspx), you can use their first example to check for querystring parameters instead of http method.